# How to check if duplicate rule has alert checkbox checked on create in Apex?

Tags: apex

I have a duplicate rule enabled in my org which has On Create set to Allow and the alert checkbox checked(although the user could set the alert to false as well).

Now I want to check if the alert is checked or not on the Apex and throw the alert or save the account (the object on which the duplicate rule is set) accordingly.

I am aware that there is a method isAllowSave() that can check if the duplicate rule will allow to save or not but I want to check if the alert is checked or not.

How do I achieve that in Apex?

Answer (score 0):

You can query the `DuplicateRule` object and reference the `SobjectType` and `IsActive` fields to determine the status.  See [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_duplicaterule.htm).